# Hooked bezier curve differen position in edit & object mode

Tags: animation

I have a drawing for a moving machine with some wires.
The wires are made by an bezier curve, and hooks to annimate it.
Hooks as I needed better control over it than cloth-sim based rope tricks.
The strange thing is that in Edit mode the curve is not the same shape as in object mode, despite the hooks.
There is a small but notable difference in position of the wire as a result.

**What can cause that ?**

I dont use bones, only parent child combinations and hooks in this drawing.

(i cannot show the drawing because of NDA contract)

Answer (score 1):

When you enter edit mode the object will be displayed as it is before the modifiers are calculated. If you use hook modifiers, they will not show up there unless you enable this box: 
[image]